# Como sumar valores traídos desde una consulta en php?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

| Total |
| --- |
| 159.00 |
| 2099.00 |
| 800.00 |
| 970.00 |
| 999.00 |

Quiero sumar los valores de la tabla pero no me sale.

Mando a traer unos valores de una tabla en mysql pero quiero que abajo salga el resultado de la suma.

Así es como los mando a traer:

```php
<?php foreach($resultados as $post): ?>
   <td><?php echo $post["Total"] ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ya intente que desde la consulta hacer un `SUM`, si hace la suma, pero solo muestra un valor en la tabla

Así es como pensé que seria

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare(
        "SELECT SUM(compra.Total) as 'sumaT', compra.Total,  compra.Total,compra.idcompra as 'idcompra', productos.NombreP as 'NombreP', cliente.Nombre as 'cliente', cliente.ApellidoPaterno as 'ap', cliente.ApellidoMaterno as 'am', FechaHora FROM compra INNER JOIN productos ON compra.idproducto=productos.idproductos INNER JOIN cliente ON compra.idcliente=cliente.idcliente WHERE compra.idcompra LIKE :busqueda OR productos.NombreP LIKE :busqueda OR cliente.Nombre LIKE :busqueda OR cliente.ApellidoPaterno LIKE :busqueda OR cliente.ApellidoMaterno LIKE :busqueda OR FechaHora LIKE :busqueda"
    );
    $statement->execute(array(':busqueda' => "%$busqueda%"));
    $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Pero me sale esto

| Total |
| --- |
| 159.00 |
| 5027.00 |

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

**Intenta esto:**

```
<?php $suma= 0; ?>
<?php foreach($resultados as $post): ?>
   <td><?php echo $post["Total"] ?></td>
   <?php $suma= $suma +$post["Total"]; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<td><?php echo $suma ?></td>
```

Comment: gracias, si funciono